# Testing keyboard input for blueprint select with react testing library

Tags: react-testing-library

I have created a codesandbox to illustrate my issue here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/floral-resonance-z2h43?file=/src/SelectExample.spec.tsx

I am trying to test the keyboard navigation within a blueprint select. That is opening the select by clicking the button, then pressing key arrows untill the desired item is active and confirming with enter which closes the select.
The functionality works perfectly fine.

I however fail to get the unit test(s) to work. As you can see in the linked sandbox a unit test that select the new item via mouseclick works.
I however have run out of ideas how to trigger the onChange of the SelectExample with keyboard inputs.

`userEvent.keyboard()`  doesn't work and fireEvent doesn't either (though I'm not sure what to target considering how blueprint implements the select and that I can only add data-testid to some elements, but going to any number of parentElements from the items which have testids didn't work either). Same issue with `userevent.type()`, unless the target for that is the desired item in which case the test pases but only because the implementation `type()` clicks on it before entering its text.

References for the keyboard input:

- https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-events/
- https://testing-library.com/docs/ecosystem-user-event/

I'd appreciate any input.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: got help here: https://github.com/testing-library/user-event/issues/835